# Why my hadoop can not understand -chmod command?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, chmod

I am trying to install hive to my local system through this link: https://www.dezyre.com/hadoop-tutorial/install-hive ; But when I try to execute the command `hadoop dfs –chmod 765 /user/hive/warehouse` it says that use of this script is deprecated and suggests to use hdfs command for. But the hdfs command(`hdfs dfs –chmod 765 /user/hive/warehouse`) doesn't work neither. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

I also tried to execute commands with `fs` instead of `dfs`. But I get the `–chmod: Unknown command` error message with hadoop and `Error: Could not find or load main class fs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fs` with hdfs.

This the exact error message when I try to execute `hadoop dfs –chmod 765 /user/hive/warehouse`:

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

–chmod: Unknown command
```

Comment: I think it's either ```hdfs dfs``` or ```hadoop fs``` have you tried the latter?

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski I tried all the combinations :)

Comment: @Mohsen Eimany to me it looks like it has something to do with installation, either you've not set PATH correctly, or it didn't get installed properly, since you're getting ClassNotFoundException. Were you able to run any other ```hadoop``` or ```hdfs dfs``` commands?

Comment: **`hadoop fs -chmod ...`** is the correct syntax, see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#chmod. My guess is that dash in `-chmod`  is actually some other character if you copy/paste it from that tutorial site.